Regexp : any chr but ignore word
Trying to capture server names from string.
A server name can be

letters + digits
letters + digits + letters (but not 'root')

Problem is that in circumstances the word 'root' gets added to the end of the string by the data source.
ab-vol-bapp000123-use-dev
ab-vol-bapp000123sql-use-dev

ab-vol-bapp000123root-use-dev
ab-vol-bapp000123sqlroot-use-dev

In the above cases, I need to get either

app000123

Or

app000123sql

However, struggling to capture the chrs after the digits whilst ignoring/excluding 'root'
This is my best attempt:
(^ab-vol-)   # literal
([a-z]{2,4}) # 2-4 alphas
([0-9]{4,6}) # 4-6 numerics
(
  (?!root)   # ignore 'root'
  [a-z]{0,4} # 0-4 alphas
)?

Obviously my "ignore 'root'" is not doing as described (last test line below fails), and I can see why - I just don't know what the alternative answer is 
Appreciate any guidance!
Thanks
(Notes :Working in AWS redshift)


What's the context for this?  What language?  Surely it would be better to use your simple regex and then search the matched string for literal "root".

How about ^(?:ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})(.*?)(?:(?:root)?-use-dev)$?

What you might do is match as least as possible 0-4 chars and assert that to the right is either the word "root" or a hyphen or the end of the string.
^(ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})([a-z]{0,4}?)(?=root\b|-|$)

The pattern matches

^ Start of string
(ab-vol-) Capture the literal text
([a-z]{2,4}) Capture 2-4 chars a-z
([0-9]{4,6}) Capture 4-6 digits
([a-z]{0,4}?) Capture 0-4 times a char a-z, as least as possible
(?= Positive lookahead, assert the to the right of the current position is

root\b|-|$ Match either the word root or a hyphen or assert the end of the string


) Close the lookahead

See a regex demo.

If you just want to match all chars that are not followed by the word "root", you could match all chars a-z except for r, and then only match r when not directly followed by oot and a word boundary.
 (^ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})([a-qs-z]*(?:r(?!oot\b)[a-qs-z]*)*)

See a regex demo.

I added a negative lookahead to match 0-4 letters that are not followed by "root".
(^ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})(?:(?!root)[a-z]){0,4}?

Result:

Or without the last ?:
(^ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})(?:(?!root)[a-z]){0,4}

Result:


You can lazily match letters after digits up to where root possibly occurs before a word boundary:
\b[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*?(?=(?:root)?\b)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Evq49E/2

Another way is to make use of the common end suffix and write a much simple regex:
^(?:ab-vol-)([a-z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,6})(.*?)(?:(?:root)?-use-dev)$


Note that, you may not really want to capture the known suffix and prefix:

(?:ab-vol-): is a non-capture group including the prefix.

(?:(?:root)?-use-dev): is a non-capture group including the suffix.


